# R^2 function for multivariate linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am looking for an implementation of the R^2 value applicable to the predictions of multivariate linear regression on a test data set.

I read some suggestions to repeat lm() for the predicted values and then read the R^2 value from the model's summary. But I do not consider this to be a sound solution.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please elaborate more on the cross-validation score for the test dataset.

Comment: Your question seems to stem from a lack of understanding of statistics, not programming. Your question seems better suited for [stats.se] where statistical questions are welcomed, not Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see the point why R^2 shouldn't be applicable to a test data set. All it needs is the Residual Sum of Squares (requiring y labels) as well as the total sum of squares (requiring y labels as well). Both is provided along with a test data set.